# write more file than partition number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark, I am writing a list of distinct emails from a hive table to flat files in HDFS. 
The constraint is that my files should not contain more than 4.5M lines.

I wrote this code :

```py
df = spark.read.table(working_table).select("email").distinct()

final_df = df.withColumn(
    "rnk", 
    (F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1))) / 4500000).cast("int")
)

final_df.groupBy("rnk").count().show()

+---+-------+                                                                   
|rnk|  count|
+---+-------+
|  0|4499999|
|  1|1858773|
+---+-------+


final_df.repartition("rnk").select("email").write.csv(
    working_dir_email, mode="overwrite", compression="none"
)
```

This works almost fine, except that I always got an additional empty file :

```sh
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/emails
Found 4 items
-rw-rw-r--   3 hadoop hadoop          0 2020-02-05 17:59 /tmp/emails/_SUCCESS
-rw-rw-r--   3 hadoop hadoop          0 2020-02-05 17:59 /tmp/emails/part-00000-f724cf35-5ed8-4b7a-98c2-fc992dca9ad1-c000.csv
-rw-rw-r--   3 hadoop hadoop  173936230 2020-02-05 17:59 /tmp/emails/part-00043-f724cf35-5ed8-4b7a-98c2-fc992dca9ad1-c000.csv
-rw-rw-r--   3 hadoop hadoop  292499935 2020-02-05 17:59 /tmp/emails/part-00191-f724cf35-5ed8-4b7a-98c2-fc992dca9ad1-c000.csv
```

Can I avoid this blank file? Is there a more clever way to achieve the result  without the empty file maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `final_df.repartition("rnk")` you are not specifying the number of partitions so Spark uses the default number of partitions (200), see [`repartition()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition). 
You can easily check this by:

```
final_df = final_df.repartition("rnk")
print(final_df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

The empty file corresponds to the empty partitions.

Another way to achieve what you want is to count the number of lines in your DataFrame then divide it by the maximum number of lines you want by file rounded up. This gives you the number of files to produce:

```
nb_lines_split = 4500000
nb_lines = df.count()

nb_files = math.ceil(nb_lines / nb_lines_split)

df.repartition(nb_files).write.csv(path, mode="overwrite")
```

Comment: I thought coalesce is generally not used for increasing partitions? could you explain